# What's the security problem is a private key is leaked for a shared secret key

Tags: cryptography

in the following case, if privateKeyOfA is leaked, what's the security problem? Can someone decrypt the message without privateKeyOfB??

Aes.encrypt(privateKeyOfA, publicKeyOfB, message)
Aes.decrypt(publicKeyOfA, privateKeyOfB)

If not, I guess why we need privateKeyOfA here is for A's signature?

Comment: The problem is that an attacker can now impersonate A. B cannot tell if the message came from A, or from someone _pretending_ to be A.

Comment: yes, I know A's private key is used to sign A's message. What I'm not sure is if there is a risk that someone can decrypt the message when he knows A's private key.

Comment: If the message is encrypted with A's private key, they can already decrypt it with A's public key. Anyone can decrypt it.

Answer (score 0):

The signature is needed since the receiver must know that the message is coming from someone that he can identify. If he cannot verify the signature, this means that he doesn't know the person.

If the private key of A is compromised by a hacker, he can send messages to everybody with signature impersonating the A.

Comment: If I don't need the signature feature, what would be the best solution? I mean, in my case, it doesn't matter if the message is sent by A or not.

Comment: the private key is compromised. I can re-send you a new message and tell you that forget the previous message. Of course, only B can decrypt but this is the smallest issue here.

Answer (score 0):

A key exchange (e.g. using [DH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman_key_exchange#Description) or [ECDH](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Elliptic-curve_Diffie%E2%80%93Hellman)) would be used by A to convert `privateKeyOfA + publicKeyOfB` into an AES key. This same AES key can also be generated identically by B using `privateKeyOfB + publicKeyOfA`. All traffic between A and B would be encrypted using the same AES key.

Assuming that all public keys are known (they are public after all), then anyone who has access to privateKeyOfA can regenerate all AES keys that were generated by A to communicate with anyone. This means all traffic involving this key (messages sent or received by A, with B or anyone else) would be compromised.

But if an ephemeral version was used (like in some modes of TLS), then a new key is generated for each session, so that if 1 key is ever compromised, only this session is compromised. You can read more about [forward secrecy](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Forward_secrecy).

If the keys are used in the way you describe, then they are not used for signature.